# What programming language do you recommend to simulate the LWR equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, computer-science, computational-mathematics

I am studying models of vehicle traffic flow and in my case I have to develop the mathematical model of the LWR equation and also the respective simulation, since the LWR equation is of a hyperbolic type, the finite difference method is used, which implies having a large system of equations.In this case I have commented that Matlab has certain limitations when solving large systems of equations, so I want to know which programming languages recommend me to do the simulation

Comment: What are the limitations that matlab have in this situation precisely? Since it seems that you have considered it for some reason, knowing why you do not want to use it might help people to suggest something similar with less limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger issue that you should be considering is what numerical method you want to use to simulate this system.  The LWR model results in a hyperbolic conservation law- the model generates shocks that can be challenging to properly simulate.  Unless you're planning to put considerable effort into learning about specialized numerical methods for conservation laws, you'd be well advised to find a library routine that can handle the problem and then build your simulation around that.